# What are the best commands to troubleshoot Workload Scheduler connectivity issues

Tags: networking, workload-scheduler

What networking operating system commands are helpful when troubleshooting unlinking issues and no connections between Workload Scheduler Master, Domain Managers and Fault Tolerant Agents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Ping**

The most commonly used network tool is the ping utility. This utility is used to provide a basic connectivity test between the requesting host and a destination host. This is done by using the Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) which has the ability to send an echo packet to a destination host and a mechanism to listen for a response from this host. Simply stated, if the requesting host receives a response from the destination host, this host is reachable. This utility is commonly used to provide a basic picture of where a specific networking problem may exist. For example, if an Internet connection is down at an office, the ping utility can be used to figure out whether the problem exists within the office or within the network of the Internet provider.

Example
ping IP or Hostname

```
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN>ping www.ibm.com

Pinging e2874.dscx.akamaiedge.net   [106.19.70.123] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 106.19.70.123: bytes=32 time=55ms TTL=56
Reply from 106.19.70.123: bytes=32 time=56ms TTL=56
Reply from 106.19.70.123: bytes=32 time=55ms TTL=56
Reply from 106.19.70.123: bytes=32 time=115ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 106.19.70.123:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 55ms, Maximum = 115ms, Average = 70ms
```

2) **Tracert / traceroute**

Typically, once the ping utility has been used to determine basic connectivity, the tracert/traceroute utility can used to determine more specific information about the path to the destination host including the route the packet takes and the response time of these intermediate hosts. The tracert utility and traceroute utilities perform the same function but operate on different operating systems, Tracert for Windows machines and traceroute for Linux/*nix based machines.

Example: 
tracert www.ibm.com

```
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN>tracert Rolltide.austin.ibm.com

Tracing route to Rolltide.austin.ibm.com [9.31.172.41]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    66 ms    62 ms    59 ms  pok-vid-31a-v3037.pok.ibm.com [9.16.135.130]
  2     *       63 ms    66 ms  reserved-9-56-3-3.pok.ibm.com [9.40.2.2]
  3    57 ms    64 ms    64 ms  9.17.6.18
  4    61 ms    65 ms    64 ms  9.69.5.33
  5   115 ms   105 ms   110 ms  9.69.56.104
  6   117 ms   113 ms   111 ms  tx049-r01-a1002x-tange0-2-0.wan.ibm.com 
     [9.65.43.103]
  7   120 ms   130 ms   120 ms  9.21.4.76
  8  9.17.8.39  reports: Destination host unreachable.

   Trace complete.
```

3) **ipconfig/ifconfig**

One of the most important things that must be completed when troubleshooting a networking issue is to find out the specific IP configuration of the variously affected hosts. Sometimes this information is already known when addressing is configured statically, but when a dynamic addressing method is used, the IP address of each host can potentially change often. The utilities that can be used to find out this IP configuration information include the ipconfig utility on Windows machines and the ifconfig utility on Linux/*nix based machines

Example:
ipconfig

```
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : msci.svl.ibm.com
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.3.136
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 5:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

 Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . : 2605:7020:f2c9:3200:c9ae:db7e:1c71:4e32
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . : 2605:7020:f2c9:3200:199:6140:ad98:9d6b
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c9fe:db7e:14c1:4b39c%16
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 9.69.47.75
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::d605:ef8f:f99ae:39cf5%16

 Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . .  : 2605:6060:f2c9:3500:d84a:253:27d1:8864
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . .  : 2605:6060:f2c9:3500:d9ed:ab4:271a:f862
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::daf7:213:f7d1:8864%13
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 162.148.0.9
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::d605:98ff:fe8c:41b7%23
                                   162.148.0.1
```

4) NSlookup

Some of the most common networking issues revolve around issues with Dynamic Name System (DNS) address resolution issues. DNS is used by everyone using the Internet to resolve commonly known domain names (i.e. google.com) to commonly unknown IP addresses (i.e. 74.125.115.147). When this system does not work, most of the functionality that people are used to goes away, as there is no way to resolve this information. The nslookup utility can be used to lookup the specific IP address(es) associated with a domain name. If this utility is unable to resolve this information, there is a DNS issue. Along with simple lookup, the nslookup utility is able to query specific DNS servers to determine an issue with the default DNS servers configured on a host.

```
 C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN>nslookup www.ibm.com
 Server:  mscidc01
 Address:  10.0.6.21

 Non-authoritative answer:
 Name:    e28f4.dscx.akamaiedge.net
 Addresses:  2001:428:3805:182::b3a
          2001:438:3806:18b::b3f
          102.84.07.134
 Aliases: www.ibm.com
          www-int.ibm.com.cs186.net
          www2.ibm.com.edgekey.net
```

5) Netstat

Often, one of the things that are required to be figured out is the current state of the active network connections on a host. This is very important information to find for a variety of reasons. For example, when verifying the status of a listening port on a host or to check and see what remote hosts are connected to a local host on a specific port. It is also possible to use the netstat utility to determine which services on a host that is associated with specific active ports.

Example: netstat

```
  C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN>netstat

  Active Connections

   Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
   TCP    9.76.31.11:48784       bld-vo-lb-vip01:5060   ESTABLISHED
   TCP    9.76.31.11:49734       b03stlbcl001:1533      ESTABLISHED
   TCP    9.76.31.11:51520       sf2:3381               CLOSE_WAIT
   TCP    9.76.31.11:53389       sf2:3381               CLOSE_WAIT
```

You can use all of these commands would troubleshooting linking fault tolerant agents, dynamic agents, connectivity to DB, Websphere connections and communications between master and agents.

```
 You will also need to make sure you have the following:

 a) Hostname and IP address of systems in question
 b) Port number assigned to /MDM/Agent/WebSphere/DB
 c) Fire walls or DMZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use **telnet**

For example from master you can test the connection to an FTA which is installed to a server with ip address: 1.2.3.4 and the netman port is set to default (31111).

Issue

```
telnet 1.2.3.4 31111
```

There might be a firewall that blocks the connection to the port if the connection is refused or timed out.